# Writing a query using Cakephp 3 query builder

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to re-write an existing website in CakePHP 3

I have a query

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT p.name, p.description, p.category_id, s.name as size_name, p.id, s.id as size_id
    FROM products p
    INNER JOIN sizes s ON s.category_id = p.category_id
    WHERE p.id = 588
) T1

LEFT JOIN 
( 
    SELECT pp.product_id, pp.price, pp.id, pp.size_id
    FROM products_prices pp

) T2
ON T1.size_id = T2.size_id AND T1.id = T2.product_id
```

products `belongsTo` Categories and Categories `hasMany` So if a product `x` `belongsTo` category `A`and category `A`has 4 sizes. this means the `products_prices` will have 4 prices one for each sizes

How I can optimize or rewrite this query in Cakephp 3 query builder?

Comment: What's wrong with it as it stands?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to obtain and also show your efforts so far.

Comment: Can you provide model association which you defined in CakePHP model?